# min and max jQuery character counter

Tags: javascript, jquery

There are many max character counters in jQuery.

Has anyone found any useful *min* character counters?

I'm looking for something like what StackOverflow uses when creating a comment:

[image: n chars to go]

Comment: What do you want to know? It is basic math, `#minChars - #currentChars`. Have you tried anything? Or have a look at SO's source code...

Comment: I'm looking for a plugin that already does this, I'm lazy,... and yes I have a basic grasp of the maths.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```
var min = 15;
$("#idOfTextbox").keydown(function() {
    if(this.value.length < min) {
        // Min notice
    } else {
        // Current count
    }
});
```

Comment: How would you prevent them from typing say if they reached 12 characters?

Comment: I would add a max var and then 'this.value = this.value.substring(0,max);' when the length is larger the the max.